# Displaying input field overflow

Tags: jquery, html

I have some input fields that can be filled with long emails or URLs that are cut off by the maximum field length that I can allow on the form. I've seen forms where hovering over the field makes the full content of the field appear outside the boundries, something like below.

[image]

Does anyone know how this is done?  I tried giving the field an overflow-x:visible style but that didn't work.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: bug in your browser may be..

Comment: Are you saying overflow-x:visible should have worked?  I'm running the latest Chrome browser.

Comment: no i mean the text wrapping out of the textbox is not a normal behavior.. check it on any other browser too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this example

HTML

```
<input type=text value="http://www.woolworthsglobalroaming.com.au">
<span>http://www.woolworthsglobalroaming.com.au</span>
```

CSS

```
span, input{
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:1em;
   padding:5px 10px;
}

span{
   position:absolute;
   left:15px;
   top:12px;
   z-index:3;
   display:none;
}
```

jQuery/Javascript

```
$(function(){
   $('input').mouseover(function(){
       var val = $(this).val();
      $(this).val('');
      $('span').show();
  });

  $('input').mouseout(function(){
      var val = $('span').text();
      $(this).val(val);
      $('span').hide();
    });
```

});

If you wanna play around with it you can use this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyUen/16/)